# How can I calculate the gravity constant $g$ of a video game, that is displaying frames at $60\,\text{Hz}$, in relation to $9.8\,\text{m/s}^2$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, simulations

How can I calculate the gravity or "$g$"  of a video game displaying frames at $60\,\text{Hz}$, to $9.8\,\text{m/s}^2$?

Please let me know if you need any more parameters or details or if something is not clear!

Comment: Absolutely unclear what you're asking about. If your video game is situated on earth, then the very same `g` value of 9.81 m/s2 should be used in your game's physics model, no matter what the frame rate is. Or are you asking for a unit conversion from m/s2 to something like pixel/frame2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually gave this as a project to my students to do with Super Mario. The trick is to use this fantastic software called [Tracker Video Analysis](https://physlets.org/tracker/) which allows you to analyse video files to find the position, velocity, and acceleration of different objects. You'll need some scale of reference to be able to do this (I believe my students used Mario's height to be 2 m, however debatable that is!) but you'll have to figure out a reference from your own game.

You'll need to have a video of your game that Tracker will accept (it automatically scales the time axis using the FPS of the video, but you can change that in the options) and then "track" the motion of a mass, from which everything else follows. Of course, it might be very likely that you (like my students) will not find your game to be particularly physically accurate! Mario certainly doesn't seem to be, if you assume him to be 2 m tall.

[image]

The image above is tracking Mario's jump, the blue bar on the screen sets the conversion between "metres" and "pixels", and the graphs on the right show the $x$ and $y$ positions of the tracked object as a function of time. I was actually quite surprised to see how the $x$ velocity is nearly constant and how parabolic the $y$ trajectory was, given that this is a video game. However the downward acceleration doesn't turn out to be $g$, I believe.

Comment: Well, I'm sure  $a = g$ will be true if you adjust the spatial units, or I would have thought Mario to be closer to 150 cm FWIW.  But I agree that in general  the effective "g" in video games is all over the map.

Comment: Possibly. I don't have the data on me now, but I remember it to be off by a factor of 2, so maybe a little shorter? Incidentally, the last "jump" that Mario does at the end of the level was particularly odd: I seem to remember him reaching a terminal velocity very quickly as he jumps to reach the flagpole(?).

Comment: You might enjoy [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Power-Up-Unlocking-Hidden-Mathematics-Video/dp/0691161518)

Comment: What an interesting book! I actually got the idea from Rhett Allain's articles on Wired: [The Physics of Angry Birds](https://www.wired.com/2010/10/physics-of-angry-birds/).

Comment: I did not understand the question at all, but apparently you've got what was wanted here. 
 @CarlWitthoft, you could presumably compute it the other way around: Assume that the acceleration is $g$ and then determine the implied height of Mario.